# How to relabel the database name in a prometheus postgresql scrape config?

Tags: postgresql, prometheus, prometheus-postgres-exporter

I'm already relabeling other things, but the `datname` is not working.

```
        relabel_configs:
          - source_labels: [datname]
            regex: "Prefix-.+"
            replacement: "Static"
            target_label: datname
```

The `datname` label is also not present in service discovery. Can this be relabeled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, but it needs to be done in the `metric_relabel_configs` part, see https://grafana.com/docs/grafana-cloud/account-management/billing-and-usage/control-prometheus-metrics-usage/usage-reduction/ for more details. Summary copied here:

> Relabel_config in a Prometheus configuration file
>
> You can apply a relabel_config to filter and manipulate labels at the
> following stages of metric collection:
>
> **Target selection** in the `relabel_configs` section of a `scrape_configs` job. This allows you to use a `relabel_config` object
> to select targets to scrape and relabel metadata created by any
> service discovery mechanism.
>
> **Metric selection** in the `metric_relabel_configs` section of a `scrape_configs` job. This allows you to use a `relabel_config` object
> to select labels and series that should be ingested into Prometheus
> storage.
>
> **Remote Write** in the `write_relabel_configs` section of a `remote_write` configuration. This allows you to use a
> `relabel_config` to control which labels and series Prometheus ships
> to remote storage.

So finally this is working:

```
        metric_relabel_configs:
          - source_labels: [datname]
            regex: "Prefix-.+"
            replacement: "Static"
            target_label: datname
```